# Exception CreateSymbolicLink error(183) Cannot create a file when that file already exists

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I am getting this error when trying to run the wordcount example from the hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.3.1.jar that comes with Hadoop.

```
Exception message: CreateSymbolicLink error (183): Cannot create a file when that file already exists.



Shell output:         1 file(s) moved.
"Setting up env variables"
"Setting up job resources"


[2021-09-27 16:43:36.455]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1.
[2021-09-27 16:43:36.455]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1.
For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://DESKTOP-0N6IMAQ:8088/cluster/app/application_1632774426206_0006 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
. Failing the application.
2021-09-27 16:43:36,780 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

This is the line that I am submitting

> hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.3.1.jar wordcount /input.txt /output.txt

Answer (score 1):

Your output file already exist. Change the name of output file.

```
hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.3.1.jar wordcount /input.txt /output2.txt
```